# Using for loop in MAP function

Tags: python

How to write the following code using for loop?

```
circle_areas = [3.56773, 5.57668, 4.00914, 56.24241, 9.01344, 32.00013]
result = list(map(round, circle_areas, range(1,7)))
print(result)
```

Comment: Is this a question for a class you're trying not to study for?  :D   Did you google it first?  https://www.journaldev.com/22960/python-map-function. Please see the instructions for how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list and apply `round()` to each item, using the index value of current item:

```
result = []
for area in circle_areas[:]:
    result.append(round(area,circle_areas.index(area)+1))

print(result) # [3.6, 5.58, 4.009, 56.2424, 9.01344, 32.00013]
```